# Checking non existing file with serverspec

Tags: ruby, integration-testing

I am new writing tests with serverspec. I really like it because it's clear and fast. But I found a problem.
It is possible to check if a file is not existing using the file type? I try adding `not` and `!` everywhere but seems not working.

For the moment I can achieve the expected behaviour using:

```
describe command('ls /etc/myfile') do
      its(:stderr) { should match /No such file or directory/ }
end
```

But I would like to make it cleaner with a kind of:

```
describe file ('/etc/myfile') do
  it { not should be file }
end
```

Someone has any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'should_not' expectation is what you are looking for:

```
  describe file ('/etc/myfile') do
    it { should_not be_a_file }
  end
```